# Why is Javascript Async not working in Parallel inside Chrome extension

Tags: javascript

I am working on a chrome extension. Somehow, the extension is blocking the website from loading when I use while loop inside an async function.

For simplicity, I went to the website, opened Chrome Dev Inspector and ran this code in console:

```
async function testFunction(){
   while(1) {}
}

testFunction()
```

Which is an infinite loop inside async. Async is supposed to work in parallel so it shouldn't cause any problem for the website from loading, but it did. The website stopped loading any further. How did I confirm it? I couldn't move the scrollbar at all, it stopped working.

**EDIT:**
Since I know now that Asynchronus isn't really Parallel like Multi-threading, I would like to add the real problem I am facing and want to ask how to solve it:

Inside "FOR loop", I need to inject iframe and then need to wait for it to load. After that, do some processing on iframe, loop ends. For the next iteration, iframe SRC is replaced with another SRC and the process from before repeats. The problem is that I have to wait for iframe load to complete and it can't be done with while loop(it stops the loading of iframe in itself, which ruins the whole point) . What do you suggest?

Comment: That loop will only run in true parallel if you put it in a Web worker. Javascript is still single threaded. Using `async` doesn't change that fact

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of it so we can suggest some alternative approach?

Comment: @EliasSoares I need to inject iframe in a website and then wait for this iframe to load. Only when this iframe loads, I can go forward with working on this iframe. Also, I am avoiding setting eventhandler( iframe onload) with Callbacks because only when I process this single iframe completely can I move to loading another url in the same iframe. Don't need async necessarily, just need the stop/wait between "iframe loading" and "processing it"

Comment: The right way is with the onload event of iframe, I really can't understand why you won't use it. But you can also avoid the crashing effect of a loop by putting it inside a setInterval() timer, so it will run the code periodically without locking the execution of rest of the process.

Comment: @EliasSoares There is only 1 iframe Object.  Loop 2,3,4 etc are going to make changes to the same iframe Object. If I leave Loop 1 to iframe.onload, the execution will go forward to Loop 2, which will make changes to the Iframe Object needed by Loop 1.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no concurrent execution model (except for web workers, I think). If you have an infinite loop, everything is blocked.

`async` is just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) building on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), which try to [avoid the callback hell](https://blog.hellojs.org/asynchronous-javascript-from-callback-hell-to-async-and-await-9b9ceb63c8e8).

For example this article gives more insight: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff (there are many more)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concept of asynchronous programming and thread-based programming, also difference between them.

In a traditional, non-threaded environment, when a function must wait on an external event (such as a network event, a keyboard or mouse event, or even a clock event), the program must wait until that event happens.

In a multi-threaded environment, many individual threads of programming are running at the same time. (Depending upon the number of CPUs and the support of the operating system, this may be literally true, or it may be an illusion created by sophisticated scheduling algorithms). For this reason, multi-threaded environments are difficult and involve issues of threads locking each other’s memory to prevent them from overrunning one another.

In an asychronous environment, a single process thread runs all the time, but it may, for event-driven reasons (and that is the key), switch from one function to another. When an event happens, and when the currently running process hits a point at which it must wait for another event, the javascript core then scans its list of events and delivers the next one, in a (formally) indeterminate (but probably deterministic) order, to the event manager.

You can read the full article from here

https://medium.com/@punitkmr/does-async-programming-mean-multi-threading-fb8d1add56dc